# ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener does not respond on certain API-Level

Tags: android, user-interface, expandablelistview

My app's main ui has a navigation-drawer containing an ExpandableListView.
Everything works fine on many devices.

But using Samsung devices with Android 4.4+ the view does not respond to onGroupClicks. LongClicks work just fine. Also using exactly the same device with an older API Level works. Tested with Galaxy S5 and Galaxy Tab 3.

The listeners method is simply not called.

Has anyone experienced this problem before?

Comment: Can you post group item layout?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem myself by now.
But I still don't know why this only affects certain devices.

Long story short:
I overwrote the invalidate method and called setCheckedState which gave no exception/freeze/strange behaviour whatsoever - just not reacting at all.